# How can we get the path of the file that opened to a default program by double clicking on the file

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an application in which a file with specific filetype will open to our application while double click on the file.Then how we get the path of the file that opened to a default program by double clicking on that file .

Example :
We can open any mp3 file to windows media player by double clicking on that mp3 file from any where in the system.Then how windows media player get the path of the mp3 file to load.

Comment: Can you show us the part of your program where you need it? Are you using a console or a winform?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Main` method will take it as parameter.

```
static void Main(string[] Args)
```

Comment: This only works with a console, but according to his tags I think he wants to use a winform.

Comment: @CurlyB **No**. it works with any kind of exe. console,winforms, wpf etc. Every executable has an entry point which can take arguments.

Comment: Sorry, you're right of course. I forgot the main program completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx) and get [`ProcessStartInfo.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename.aspx) property.